# Method to evaluate $\mathbf{E}[B(t)\cdot e^{B(t)}]$, where $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $\xi$ be a normally distributed random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$, and that we have the formula

$$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}[e^{\lambda \xi}]=e^{\frac{1}{2} \lambda^2}, \hspace{3mm} -\infty<\lambda <\infty
\end{equation}
$$

I will like to evaluate $\mathbf{E}[B(t)\cdot e^{B(t)}]$, where $B(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion.

Am I allowed to do the following:

$$\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}[B(t)\cdot e^{B(t)}] = \mathbf{E}[B(t)]\cdot \mathbf{E}[e^{B(t)}]?
\end{equation}
$$

I'm still new to the topics on Brownian motion, so some clarification will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, $B(t)\sim N(0,t)$. But no,  you are not allowed to pretend that $\mathbf E(B(t)\exp(B(t))=\mathbf E(B(t))\mathbf E(\exp(B(t))$ because the random variables $B(t)$ and $\exp(B(t))$ are not independent.  (In fact, they are positively correlated, so your proposal would give the wrong answer.)

Instead use the fact that $\mathbf E\exp(\lambda B(t))=\exp(t\lambda^2/2)$, or rather, that $$\mathbf E(\frac d{d\lambda} \exp(\lambda B(t)) = \frac d{d\lambda} \exp(t\lambda^2/2)=t\lambda\exp(t\lambda^2/2).$$
When evaluated at $\lambda=1,$ you get the desired result.

The justification of the interchange of expectation and differentiation with respect to $\lambda$ is left to you. It does not involve any Brownian-motion specific reasoning, and hardly any specific facts about the normal distribution.

Comment: Sorry, but I am somewhat confused.. How did $\frac{d}{d\lambda}$ appear and where did the $B(t)$ before $exp(B(T))$ go to?

Comment: $d/dl \exp (lb) = b\exp(lb)$ and if $l=1$, you get $b\exp b$.

Comment: Ah thanks fr the clarification! In which area can I find that particular expression? I've not learnt that (at least I don't remember) in my calculus courses and I will like to find out more about it.

Comment: oh wait a sec.. I see it! Blur me.. I did not see it as differentiation :( Thanks again and sorry about that!

Comment: This is one of the tricks that Richard  Feynman liked to use (and brag about).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want since $B(t)\ and\ e^{B(t)}$ are dependent.  The basic formula you need is $E=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^xf(x)dx$, where f(x) is the probability density function for B(t).

Comment: If I were to go by that method, will $x$ in the integral be $B(t)\cdot e^{B(t)}$?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  x is the dummy variable for f(x) which is the the probability density function for the random variable (B(t)).  In other words $P(B(t)\le b)=\int_{-\infty}^b f(x)dx$